# 25 Hours day add hour and returns previous hour

Tags: java, calendar

I have a method that adds 1 hour to a `Calendar` date:

```
calendarDate.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 60);
```

I need that If the `calendarDate` is 31 october at 02:00 and you add one hour, it returns again 02:00 because that day at that hour there is an hour change.

How can I do that?

…or which method should I use to return again 02:00 when I add one hour?

I want to add 1 hour to `calendarDate` and in the case of 31/10/2021 02:00 if you add one hour due to hour change I want to show again 02:00 instead of 03:00 any idea?

EDIT:
doing calendar.getTime() output:
before adding 1 hour:Sun Oct 31 01:00:00 CEST 2021
after adding 1 hour:Sun Oct 31 02:00:00 CEST 2021
before adding 1 hour Sun Oct 31 02:00:00 CET 2021
after adding 1 hour Sun Oct 31 03:00:00 CET 2021

Comment: There's a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` you can use for exactly that.

Comment: I suggest [ZonedDateTime](https://www.baeldung.com/java-daylight-savings).

Comment: Use `java.time.ZonedDateTime` class `plusHours` or `plusMinutes` method

Comment: Note that this "hour change" actually just changes the time zone, so CEST becomes CET etc. - hence 02:00 CET is 03:00 CEST.

Comment: This "hour change" does NOT change the time zone, in the sense of a Java TimeZone, as a previous commentator suggested.  It changes the offset.  Many Java TimeZones use two different offsets, at different times of the year.  Any given location stays in the same TimeZone all year round.

Comment: @user16320675 yes calendar time zone is Europe, but with that code adding 1 hour, as I show in the post from 02:00 shows 03:00 but with the time change it should show again 02:00 and I don´t know why

Comment: Totally correct what @DawoodibnKareem wrote, in `java.time` there's no `TimeZone` but `ZoneOffset` and `ZoneId`.

Comment: @user16320675 if you add to calendar 1 hour shows again 02:00 instead of 03:00 ?

Comment: @deHaar is right.  `TimeZone` is the name of a class in `java.util`, which was around before Java 8.  If you're using the new Java 8 `java.time` package, you should use `ZoneId` in place of `TimeZone`; although conceptually they're the same thing.

Comment: @user16320675 yes my problem is that is changing from CEST to CET so it doesn´t shows 02:00 again

Comment: @user16320675 I have added the output in the post

Comment: Thanks going to try to fix it, I  think if I only work with CEST will solve the problem right? @user16320675

Comment: is set from a Date @user16320675 if the date reads in CET instead of CEST I should change to read all dates in CEST and then it would be okay i think

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can use a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` for your desires:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // create a ZonedDateTime on Oct 31 at 0 o'clock in Berlin (has DST switches)
    ZonedDateTime oct312021Berlin = ZonedDateTime.of(
                2021, 10, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")
            );
    // print that once
    System.out.println(oct312021Berlin);
    // then add different amounts of hours
    for (int h = 1; h <= 5; h++) {
        // and print each result
        System.out.println(oct312021Berlin.plusHours(h));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2021-10-31T00:00+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
2021-10-31T01:00+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
2021-10-31T02:00+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
2021-10-31T02:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
2021-10-31T03:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
2021-10-31T04:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
```

In the output, you can see the effect in the difference between line 3 and 4, which is not the time of day but the offset of the time zone (which stays the same).

Note: This example output implicitly calls `ZonedDateTime.toString()`, which might not provide the desired result. You can format the values by `ZonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter)` as desired.